# Remapping key in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, lts

In my PC,

the @ and " need to be interchanged on keyboard.
As they are printed according to that in the key board.

Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: I think you just need to select the right keyboard layout? Have a look at your settings

Comment: Make sure you don't have the US layout set on a UK keyboard or vise versa. The @ symbol is over the 2 in the US and next to the enter key in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you use an American keyboard with UK English selected. Upper right corner click on EN1 and change it to EN2